# Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

When I try this command

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(s^2 - u)^2 - 1], {s, m, Infinity}, Assumptions -> u > 2 && m > 10]
```

*Mathematica* declares that the integral does not converge on `{m, ∞}`

The integral, though, is clearly convergent, and *Mathematica* has no trouble evaluating it at any value of $u > 1$. A command such as

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(s^2 - 20.1)^2 - 1], {s, m, Infinity}, Assumptions -> m > 10]
```

works fine.

Comment: Version 12.0  returns the input in several minutes.

Comment: Still is not solved though even in 13.2.1.

Answer (score 14):

To make your integral convergent, you should have assumed `m > Sqrt[u + 1]`; then, you shouldn't have assumed other conditions for `m`. If we do that, we get a pretty nice result :

```
int[u_, m_] = Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[(s^2 - u)^2 - 1], {s, m, Infinity}, 
                                   Assumptions -> u > 2 && m > Sqrt[u + 1]]
```

> ```
>  EllipticF[ArcSin[m/Sqrt[-1 + u]], (-1 + u)/(1 + u)]/Sqrt[1 + u] + 
>   I (2/Sqrt[-1 + m^2 - u] + EllipticK[2/(1 + u)]/Sqrt[1 + u])
> ```

```
% // TraditionalForm
```

[image: result]

**Edit**

This result isn't manifestly real while the integral  should be.  The problem comes from the fact that `ArcSin` is a well defined function assuming an appropriate convention on certain region. Evaluating numerically  the result we get nonvanishing imaginary part because *Mathematica* assumes an arbitrary ( inadequate in this case) convention. However, we should simply cancel that part. We can see this problem defining a numerical integral :

```
nint[u_, m_] := NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[(s^2 - u)^2 - 1],
                                  {s, m, Infinity} ] /; u > 2 && m > Sqrt[u + 1]
```

e.g.

```
{ int[3, 3] // N, nint[3, 3]}
```

> ```
>  {0.38116 + 0.894427 I, 0.38116}
> ```

```
{ int[5, 6] // N, nint[5, 6]}
```

> ```
>  {0.175115 + 0.365148 I, 0.175115}
> ```

Thus the result itself is correct but the symbolic integral `int` should be supplemented by an adequate rule, in our case it is simply `int[u,m] -> Re @ int[u,m]`.

Comment: this explain is nice.

Answer (score 9):

Artes has already explained how `Integrate[]` goofs up. My personal opinion is that `Integrate[]`'s handling of elliptic integrals is rather suboptimal in general, so I'll supply a closed form that you might be interested in:

```
intTrue[u_, m_] := InverseJacobiCN[(m^2 - Sqrt[u^2 - 1])/(m^2 + Sqrt[u^2 - 1]),
                                   (1 + u/Sqrt[u^2 - 1])/2]/(2 (u^2 - 1)^(1/4))
```

(I derived this using formula 266.00 in [Byrd and Friedman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0))

Test, with Artes's cases:

```
N[{intTrue[3, 3], intTrue[5, 6]}, 20] // Chop
   {0.38116007331988842687, 0.17511500066578163200}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the variable substitution

```
s^2 - u == x
```

the integration is now

```
Integrate[(1/(2*Sqrt[u + x]))*(1/Sqrt[-1 + x^2]), {x, m^2 - u, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> u > 2 && m > Sqrt[u + 1]]
```

and gives

```
EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[1 + u]/m], (-1 + u)/(1 + u)]/Sqrt[1 + u]
```

which is the real part of the above result. (Argument of Arcsin reversed!)