# Mathematica gives wrong result while Wolfram|Alpha is correct

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, wolfram-alpha-queries

[image: Mathematica and Wolfram|Alpha output]

Why does *Mathematica* and *Wolfram|Alpha* give different results based upon the same code?

I know *Wolfram|Alpha*'s `7.85` is correct.

Comment: Try: `NIntegrate[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], {t, 0, 2}]`

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. `Integrate[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], t]; N[(%/.t->2), 20]` gives the same wrong result.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is returning numerical integration because the symbolic integration is timing out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Artes' guess seems basically right.  Here is a way to reach the correct result.  First, the antiderivative returned by *Mathematica*:

```
i0 = FullSimplify[
       Integrate[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], t],
       t > 0]

(* (2 (Sqrt[16 - 2 I (-5 I + Sqrt[11]) t^2] Sqrt[8 + I (5 I + Sqrt[11]) t^2] (
     5 (-5 I + Sqrt[11]) EllipticE[ArcSin[1/2 t Root[9 - 5 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]], 
                                   1/18 (7 - 5 I Sqrt[11])] -
     (11 I + 5 Sqrt[11]) EllipticF[ArcSin[1/2 t Root[9 - 5 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]],
                                   1/18 (7 - 5 I Sqrt[11])]) + 
     9/2 t (16 - 20 t^2 + 9 t^4) Root[36 + 10 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 3])) /
       (27 Sqrt[(-5 - I Sqrt[11]) (16 - 20 t^2 + 9 t^4)])  *)
```

If we add to `Pi` to the two `ArcSin` expressions in `i0`, we get another antiderivative:

```
i1 = i0 /. a_ArcSin :> Pi + a;

D[i0, t] // FullSimplify[#, t > 0] &
D[i1, t] // FullSimplify[#, t > 0] &

(* Sqrt[16 - 20 t^2 + 9 t^4]
   Sqrt[16 - 20 t^2 + 9 t^4] *)
```

It turns out that `i1` is the continuation of `i0`:

```
Plot[{i0, i1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, Blue], Directive[Thick, Red]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence,

```
(i1 /. t -> 2.) - (i0 /. t -> 0.) 
(* 7.847 - 8.88178*10^-16 I *)
```

yields the correct (approximate) result.

Such are the pitfalls of elliptic integrals and their symbolic antiderivatives, I suppose.    `NIntegrate` bypasses antiderivatives and estimates the integral from the (real) values of the integrand.  It should never encounter such problems.

---

**Further analysis**

The plots below show the discontinuities in the `EllipticE` and `EllipticF` that lead to the incorrect value for `Integrate`.  The discontinuities violate the conditions necessary to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (an antiderivative is by definition supposed to be differentiable and therefore continuous).

```
{x0, x1} = FixedPoint[  (* find the discontinuity *)
  Function[{x}, If[Im@Chop[i0 /. t -> x] != 0, {First[#], x}, {x, Last[#]}]][Mean[#]] &,
  {1.599, 1.6}]

Table[
  With[{part = part, ell = ell}, 
   ContourPlot[
    part[ell[ArcSin[1/2 t Root[9 - 5 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 4]],
             1/18 (7 - 5 I Sqrt[11])]] /. t -> x + I y,
    {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1},
    MaxRecursion -> 3, PlotPoints -> 25,
    AxesOrigin -> {x0, 0}, Axes -> True, 
    AxesStyle -> Directive[Thin, Red], PlotLabel -> part@ell]
   ],
  {ell, {EllipticE, EllipticF}}, {part, {Re, Im}}] // GraphicsGrid

(* {1.5991767250934696`, 1.5991767250934699`} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the real-valued antiderivative, piece together different branches:

```
anti = Piecewise[{
    {i0, -x0 <= t <= x0},
    {i0 /. a_ArcSin :> Pi + a, t >= x1},
    {i0 /. a_ArcSin :> -Pi + a, t <= -x1}},
   Indeterminate];

Plot[anti, {t, -4, 4},
 Mesh -> {{-x0, x0}}, MeshShading -> {Green, Blue, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I have a question -- what an antiderivative is? My guess is the stuff one obtains after integration.

Comment: @LeoFang  That's basically right. An [antiderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) of a function $f$ is a function $F$ whose derivative $F'$ equals $f$.  Also called an (indefinite) integral.  It's the stuff returned by `Integrate[f[t], t]` (with no interval for `t`).  You may know it by a different name.

Answer (score 5):

This does not really answer the question as to why *Mathematica*'s `Integrate` yields an apparently wrong answer. This simply states why the two answers are different. It seems Wolfram|Alpha does not attempt to do a symbolic integration (which is what your input asks for) before taking its numerical value. As I stated in my comment, using `NIntegrate` gives the correct answer similar to `Wolfram|Alpha`. So, in short, `Wolfram|Alpha` uses `NIntegrate` directly. Which is why the following input yields the right answer in *Mathematica*:

```
NIntegrate[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], {t, 0, 2}]
```

> 7.847

Comment: To get an insight what might go wrong see this answer: [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082). You can see there are elliptic functions as well as `ArcSin`, together they can produce unwanted imaginary result. There is another problem with real part but I guess they both could be resonably explained (as an inproper phase rule)

Comment: @Artes. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just use NIntegrate to get a numerical answer in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer, but comparing the answer with Maple, and also showing step by step integration using Rubi, which might help point to where Mathematica went wrong.

### Mathematica Integrate

```
r = Simplify@Integrate[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[r /. t -> 2 - r /. t -> 0, 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Maple

```
r:=int(sqrt( (2*t)^2+(4-3*t^2)^2),t=0..2);
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
evalf[20](r);
7.8469978240383303061+7.9695375019434005093*10^(-20)*I
```

`F` in the above is `EllipticF` and `E` is `EllipticE`. So both Maple and Mathematica have the answer in terms of Elliptic functions. To see step by step process, with the hope to better find where the bug happens, I used Rubi:

### Rubi 4.2 step by step

```
ShowSteps = True;
r = Int[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
result = %;
N[result /. t -> 2 - result /. t -> 0, 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In one of those steps, the Integrate went wrong. Need more time to analyze.

Comment: Up to `t==Pi/2` the symbolic integration works. Then it becomes complex

Comment: @Rojo Your argument converges to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33866/mathematica-gives-wrong-result-while-wolframalpha-is-correct/33868#comment104710_33868)

Comment: Great comparison! Do you have some comment on why Rubi and Mathematica wrong results are the same? My impression was that Rubi is practically independant on Mathematica algorihms for integration.

Answer (score 3):

I observed this behavior while at a training session at Wolfram Headquarters, and there seems to be an issue with using `Integer`s here:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[(2. t)^2 + (4. - 3. t^2)^2], {t, 0, 2}] // N
(* 7.847 *)
```

Specifying `Real` numbers yields the correct result.  I can only assume that Wolfram Alpha is performing this calculation with Real numbers as well.

Comment: Note that `Integrate[Sqrt[(2. t)^2 + (4. - 3. t^2)^2], {t, 0, 2}]` returns unevaluated, so the `// N` basically converts it to an `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Thanks - I missed that.  Does this suggest that the problem is with `NIntegrate`?

Comment: No, `NIntegrate` gets it right.  The problem is that `Integrate` takes an algebraic approach, and in this case, the interval $0 \le t \le 2$ seems to cross a branch cut of the antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'm slowly going through the questions involving elliptic integral evaluations. Yet again, none of the software mentioned in this thread have managed to produce a "clean" expression. For the benefit of future readers, here's a tidier closed form for your perusal:

```
N[2 (7 Sqrt[5] + 2 (10 EllipticE[2 π/3, 11/12] + EllipticF[2 π/3, 11/12])/Sqrt[3])/9, 20]
   7.8469978240383303061

NIntegrate[Sqrt[(2 t)^2 + (4 - 3 t^2)^2], {t, 0, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   7.8469978240383303060
```