# Another fractional part related question

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Having known the fact that the evaluation of the  integrals containing fractional parts often contains
errors, I wonder if the integral below possibly evaluates to $0.7$ or this is just a coincidence that

```
N[Integrate[Tan[x] - Floor[Tan[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}], 16]
```

yields $0.6991518856432281$. How could I check if $0.7$ is or isn't the right answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you flip the area being calculated about the line $y=x$, you get that the following two integrals are equivalent:

```
Integrate[Tan[x] - Floor[Tan[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}]
Integrate[ArcTan[Ceiling[y]] - ArcTan[y], {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

The second is equal to the limit of the difference of the integral and the sum, as `n` approaches `Infinity`:

```
int = Integrate[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n > 0]
sum = Sum[ArcTan[k], {k, n}]
```

You can but you don't have to trust the Numerical Calculus package:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
NLimit[sum - int, n -> Infinity]
(*
   0.69836
*)
```

You don't have to, because the error of `sum - int` for a given `n` is less than `Pi/2 - ArcTan[n]`.  So for 6 digits of accuracy, evaluate for `n -> 10^6`.

```
sum - int /. n -> 10^6 // N
(*
   0.698359
*)
```

---

Some pictures to show the equivalence:

```
Plot[{Tan[x], Floor[Tan[x]]}, {x, 0, Pi/2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
Plot[{ArcTan[Ceiling[x]], ArcTan[x]}, {x, 0, 7}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below we can see that `sum - int` underestimates the integral and the error is actually less than `(Pi/2 - ArcTan[n])/2`, the factor of 1/2 following from the concavity of `ArcTan`.  (The error consists of "concave triangles" that fit in the space above the last triangle and below $y=\pi/2$.)

```
Show@Table[
  ParametricPlot[
   {1 - t, t}.{{x - i + 1, ArcTan[i]}, {x - i + 1, ArcTan[x]}},
   {x, i - 1, i}, {t, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Pi/2}}],
  {i, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: OK, thank you! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

We can get the result easily if we observe a simple fact, that such an integral can be evaluated symbolically:

```
Integrate[ Tan[x], {x, ArcTan[n], ArcTan[n + 1]}, Assumptions -> n  ∈ Integers && n > 0] 
- n (ArcTan[n + 1] - ArcTan[n])
```

> ```
> -n (-ArcTan[n] + ArcTan[1 + n]) + 1/2 Log[1 + (1 + 2 n)/(1 + n^2)]
> ```

Now we can just sum the above series form `n == 0` to infinity:

```
NSum[ -n (-ArcTan[n] + ArcTan[1 + n]) +   1/2 Log[1 + (1 + 2 n)/(1 + n^2)], {n, 0, ∞}]
```

> ```
> 0.69836
> ```

**Edit**

It appears that although indirectly, we can get the symbolic result as well.
We have to transform terms involving `ArcTan` to logarithms with the help of `TrigToExp`before calculating it with `Sum` (precedence is crucial) :

```
Sum[ -n (-ArcTan[n] + ArcTan[1 + n]) + 1/2 Log[1 + (1 + 2 n)/(1 + n^2)] // TrigToExp, {n, 0, ∞}] //
FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

This sum is expressed in terms of the Euler gamma function and first derivatives of the Riemann zeta function and although it doesn't seem to be real we can get the real part of it.

```
N[ Re[%], 40]
```

> ```
> 0.6983596795324668021124683422031034593401
> ```

We have had to take the real part of the sum since we've encountered an arbitrary *Mathematica* rule for calculation of logarithm function braches in the complex domain, see e.g. this post [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082)

Comment: This is a good options as well. Thank you. (+1)

Comment: Note that you can calculate this series more accurately e.g. with: `NSum[-n (-ArcTan[n] + ArcTan[1 + n]) + 
  1/2 Log[1 + (1 + 2 n)/(1 + n^2)], {n, 0, ∞}, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` which yields `0.6983596795324668`.

Comment: Ok, really nice but I'm not very surprised since `Gamma` is a generalization of `Factorial`, I wanted to update my answer here since I was sure there had to be a more elegant form but I've been busy recently, now I guess you don't expect any updates of my answer, do you?

Comment: @Chris'ssis Ok, no updates, but I really don't like few upvotes for interesting answers and I had expected to improve it considerably with more detailed discussion.

Comment: My account is going to be deleted soon. No need for further work.