# Why does this integral have a complex result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I wanted to find the normalization of distribution  F2 .

```
p = 2.2849;
p1 = 0.938/3;
p2 = 0.938/3;
p3 = 1.6;


F2 = Integrate[(s - s0)*(s + 2^2)^-2/(p^2 - s)^2, {s, s0, Infinity}]/. s0 -> (p1^2/(1 - x2 - x3) + p2^2/x2 + p3^2/x3)

nfactor = NIntegrate[F2, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}];
```

why is Mathematica producing  complex result?
while the result have to be real

Comment: Please take a minute to format your post.  Put the code in code block.  Editing help is on the right of the edit box, or press the (?) button on the edit toolbar for additional help.

Comment: This is not a very strange issue, see a closely related post explaining why it happens: [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082)

Comment: If I copy-paste your code, `Integrate` produces a `ConditionalExpression` which fails for parts of the rectangle `{x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}`. This means `NIntegrate` returns unevaluated. Did you `F2` correctly?

Comment: Why would it be real? The integrand has logs that have negative arguments in ranges `0<x2<1` and `0<x3<1`.

Comment: In[1]:= p = 2.2849;
p1 = 0.938/3;
p2 = 0.938/3;
p3 = 1.6;




F2 = Integrate[(s - s0)*(s + 2^2)^-2/(s - p^2)^2, {s, s0, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {s0 \[Element] Reals, s0 > 5.22077}] /. 
  s0 -> (p1^2/(1 - x2 - x3) + p2^2/x2 + p3^2/x3)


In[6]:= 
nfactor = 
 NIntegrate[F2, {x2, 0, 1}, {x3, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
  Method -> {GlobalAdaptive, MaxErrorIncreases -> 10000}]

Out[6]= -0.00145373 - 0.00874148 I

Comment: but the  result is  complex