# Integrating a real function I get a complex value, while after variable transformation the result is real. Bug?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions, complex

I have the following integral:

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[0.7 + 0.3*(1 + z)^3], {z, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> z ∈ Reals]

>> -3.36354 - 3.85013 I
```

The output is complex, although I used reals in the assumptions and I know that it doesn't make sense.

If I use the variable transformation:

$$z=e^{-t} - 1$$

and now integrate this:

```
Integrate[-Exp[-t]/Sqrt[(0.7 + 0.3*Exp[-3 t])], {t, 0, -∞}]

>> 3.30508
```

I am wondering why I get in the first case a complex number, but also why I get the real part also wrong.

In this case I know a variable transformation that can help, but I am wondering about other more complicated cases in which I don't know a transformation.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Try `Integrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*(1 + z)^3], z]` and check the result

Comment: I get this: $\frac{2 \sqrt[6]{-1} \sqrt[3]{7} \sqrt{(-1)^{5/6} \left(\sqrt[3]{-\frac{3}{7}} (z+1)-1\right)} \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{-\frac{3}{7}} (z+1)+\left(-\frac{3}{7}\right)^{2/3} (z+1)^2+1} F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-i (z+1) \sqrt[3]{-\frac{3}{7}}-(-1)^{5/6}}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)|\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)}{3^{7/12} \sqrt{\frac{3}{10} (z+1)^3+\frac{7}{10}}}$

Comment: The `Assumption` should be unnecessary. You'll get the same, unexpected, complex value without it, too.

Comment: But `NIntegrate` seems correct.

Comment: Yes @murray, exactly the `Assumption` is unnecessary, I just added it here for clearness. And yes @gatessucks, NIntegrate is also correct, I noticed that from the beginning too. I am using Mathematica 9.0.1.

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug?

Comment: I tried to drill down to the origin of this bug. Define the integrand `f[z_] := 1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10 (1 + z)^3]`, then evaluate the indefinite integral `int[z_] = Integrate[f[z], z]`. Close inspection reveals that `int[z]` has a discontinuity that shouldn't be there - e.g. compare `int[1.6527048]` with `int[1.6527049]`. If you evaluate `ContourPlot[Arg[int[x + I y]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` it shows the context for this discontinuity. It appears that the wrong result is due to Mathematica jumping between different branches of `Arg`, or something like that ...

Comment: Note that Integrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*(1 + z)^3], {z,0,Infinity}] does not evaluate to anything.

Comment: With v11.2.0 on a Mac, neither the original integral nor the rationalized version evaluate (i.e., returns input). However, `NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*(1+z)^3], {z, 0, Infinity}]` evaluates to `3.30508`. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 7):

Although the other answers provide correct values, I prefer that by J.M. since it touches the essence of the issue, nonetheless I'm going to provide an exact result with a bit of desirable explanation, therefore it is crucial to mention at first one of the basic elliptic integrals:
$$\int_{\infty}^{x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{4t^3-g_2 t-g_3}}=\wp^{-1}(x;g_2,g_3)$$
that is $\wp$ - the Wierstrass elliptic function, i.e is the inverse function to the above elliptic integral expressed as a function of $x$, while $g_2$ and $g_3$ are the Weierstrass invariants. **The main problem** related to **symbolic calculation of elliptic integrals** concerns of an appropriate **domain of definitions** (in the complex plane) of the the elliptic functions and its inverses.
While $\wp$ is a doubly periodic in the complex plane, it is defined in the whole complex plane except for a discrete (however infinite) set of the  lattice points, therefore we have to deal with $\wp^{-1}$ carefully. Here we plot only a finite sector of a lattice:

```
Graphics[
  Point[ Flatten[
    Table[n {-1/2, -3/2} + m {Sqrt[1], 1/Sqrt[3]}, 
          {m, -10, 10}, {n, -10, 10}], 1]]]
```

[image]

which one can simply calulate with the Weierstrass half-periods. All those functions are implemented in *Mathematica*

```
 ?**Weierstrass**
```

[image]

Among them there are new in version *11.2*: `WeierstrassE1, WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1, WeierstrassInvariantG2, WeierstrassEta1` etc.
Unfortunately they (*WRI*) have not improved various unsatisfactory issues related to calculations of elliptic functions and intgrals.

For quite a similar problem see [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082)

Of course, the integral should be real and that is a mathematical error. However, as there are many similar problematic issues (see e.g. this [anser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158654/problem-solving-third-order-non-linear-differential-equation-in-mathematica/158663#158663)), one should  expect the **revision of symbolic integration of elliptic functions** by *WRI* rather than a removing a simple bug.

To give a clarifying symbolic solution of the problem at hand, let's rewrite the integral symbolically:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{\frac{7}{10}+\frac{3}{10}(1+z)^3}}=2\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac{28}{3}+4t^3}}=-2\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}} \int_{\infty}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac{28}{3}+4t^3}}=\\=-2\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}} \wp^{-1}(1;0,-\frac{28}{3}) $$

The last function is the inverse of the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$, and the integral should be calculated automatically with *Mathematica*  in a symbolic way however it fails. Nonetheless, there are appropriate symbolic tools to verify our reasoning.

```
N[-2 Sqrt[10/3] InverseWeierstrassP[1, {0, -(28/3)}], 25] // Chop
```

> ```
> 3.305075828454599464535302
> ```

```
Plot[ WeierstrassP[-Sqrt[(3/40)] t, {0, -(28/3)}] - 1, {t, -20, 20}, 
      PlotRange -> {-5, 20}, 
      Epilog -> {PointSize[0.025], Red, Point[{3.3050758284545996`, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Let's check it numerically in another way:

```
t /. FindRoot[ WeierstrassP[-Sqrt[(3/40)] t, {0, -(28/3)}] - 1, {t, 3}]//Chop
```

> ```
> 3.30508
> ```

A hint why there is `- 3.85013 I` in the earlier version:

```
N[-2 Sqrt[10/3] InverseWeierstrassP[0, {0, -(28/3)}]]
```

> ```
> -2.22287 + 3.85013 I
> ```

and from the plot it is clear why the system (unfortunately) fails to find automatically the argument of the inverse function.

```
GraphicsRow@Table[
  ContourPlot[ p[WeierstrassP[-Sqrt[(3/40)] (x + I y), {0, -(28/3)}] - 1] == 0,
               {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ContourStyle -> Red],
  {p, {Re, Im}}]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow@Table[
  ContourPlot[ p[WeierstrassP[-Sqrt[(3/40)] (x + I y), {0, -(28/3)}] - 1],
              {x, -12, 12}, {y, -12, 12}, ColorFunction -> ColorData["SolarColors"]], 
                  {p, {Re, Im}}]
```

[image]
For a more throughout exposition this topic see e.g. [Weierstrass Elliptic and Modular Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/23), quite a brief one may be found here [Weierstrass Elliptic Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html).

**Edit**
It is worth to mention that the integral in the symbolic form hadn't been calculated in version *11.2* while since at least the version *12.1* it evaluates correctly

```
Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10 (z + 1)^3], {z, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> 1/3 Sqrt[10/7] ((3^(2/3) 7^(1/3) Gamma[1/6] Gamma[4/3])/Sqrt[Pi] 
> - 3 Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, -(3/7)])
> ```

which is equivalent to the above derivation.

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

In v11.2 the integral returns unevaluated

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*(z + 1)^3], {z, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image]

Numeric integration works

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*(z + 1)^3], {z, 0, Infinity}]

(* 3.30508 *)
```

Or simplifying the integral by change of variables. Let `t == z + 1`

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*t^3], {t, 1, Infinity}]

(* 20/3 Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 1, 7/6, -(7/3)] *)

% // N

(* 3.30508 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

The integral under consideration is an *elliptic integral*. A number of you are already familiar with how I keep complaining about suboptimal handling of elliptic integrals in general, so I'll just give the closed form and a pointer to use formula 241.00 in [Byrd/Friedman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0):

```
With[{y = 1}, 
     N[(1000000/107163)^(1/12) InverseJacobiCN[1 - 42/(7 (3 + Sqrt[3]) + y 583443^(1/6)),
                                               (2 + Sqrt[3])/4], 20]]
   3.3050758284545994645

NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[7/10 + 3/10*t^3], {t, 1, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
   3.3050758284545994682
```