# Problem solving Third order non-linear differential equation in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to find an analytical solution of the following 3rd order non-linear differential equation in *Mathematica*: $a (f'(x))^2+f'''(x)=0$ with boundary conditions $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f''(1)=1$

This how I input it in *Mathematica*.

```
DSolve[{a (f'[x])^2+f'''[x]==0, f[0]=0, f'[0]==0,f[1]=1,f''[1]=0},f[x],x]
```

> ```
> ... Dsolve: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve for the conditions
>
>     {}
> ```

Would you give any suggestions how to make it work?

Answer (score 10):

Elliptic functions are not optimally implemented in *Mathematica*, there are many examples on this site affirming this statement, and it would be reasonable to emphasise what does not work perfectly. This is the reason why `DSolve` does not provide an exact solution with coefficients determined.
However we can choose a bit more pedestriaan approach.

Taking a look at the boundary conditions we can see that the coefficient $a$ cannot be equal to $0$.
Let's denote $f'(x)=g(x)$. Now we have $g''+a\;g^2=0$. We can multiply the last equation by $g'$ and integrate it once to get ${g'}^2-4(-\frac{a}{6})g^3-g'(0)^2=0$, where we have used $f'(0)=0$. Next we multiply the equation by $(-\frac{a}{6})^2$ and substitute $w=-\frac{a}{6}g$ and we get ${w'}^2-4w^3-w'(0)^2=0$. This is the canonical differential equation for the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$ where $g_2=0$, and $g_3=-w'(0)^2$. The general solution is $w(x)=\wp(x + x_0;0,-w(0)^2)$. 
Now, recalling that $f'(x)=g(x)\;$ and $f(0)=0\;$ we have:
$$f(x)=-\frac{6}{a} \int^{x}_{0} \wp\big(s+x_0;\;0,-(\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big) ds=\\
=-\frac{6}{a} \bigg(\zeta\big(x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big)-\zeta\big(x+x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big) \bigg)$$
where $\zeta$ is the Weierstrass zeta function. Moreover we have 
$$ f'(x)=-\frac{6}{a} \wp\big(x+x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big)$$
and
$$ f''(x)=-\frac{6}{a} \wp'\big(x+x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big)$$

We can use the identity for $f'(x)$ with $x=0$ to determine $x_0$ recalling that the boundary conditions require $f'(0)=0$:
$$x_0=\wp^{-1}\big(0;\;0, -(\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big) $$ 
We need another relation to determine $f''(0)$ having $f(1)=1=f''(1)$. 
Taking definitions of $f(x)$ and $f''(x)$ we can in principle determine $f''(0)$.
We get:
$$1=-\frac{6}{a}\bigg( \zeta\big(x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big)-\zeta\big(1+x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big) \bigg)$$
and
$$1=-\frac{6}{a}\wp'\big(1+x_0;\;0,-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2\big) $$ 
*Mathematica* cannot solve these equations symbolically, even much simpler ones, e.g.

```
Reduce[2 == WeierstrassPPrime[x, {0, -4}] && 0 < x < 10, x]
```

> ```
> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.
> ```

although one can find it simply with e.g. `FindRoot`. When working with numeric functions like `FindRoot` one should be very careful to avoid possible problems with appropriate domains of functions.
Let's solve numerically the identity involving $\zeta$ with respect to $f''(0)$ for a parameter $a$ (with the former choice of branch $a<0$): and the solution (with all parameters symbolic but one - $g_3=-(-\frac{a}{6}f''(0))^2$)

```
With[{a = -7.82}, 
  w02 =(-(a/6) fb0)^2 /. Chop@
  FindRoot[-(a/6) == WeierstrassZeta[ InverseWeierstrassP[0, {0, -(a/6 fb0)^2}],
                                      {0, -(a/6 fb0)^2}] -
           WeierstrassZeta[ 1 + InverseWeierstrassP[0, {0, -(a/6 fb0)^2}],
                            {0, -(a/6 fb0)^2}],
  { fb0, 1}];
  Plot[-(a/6) (WeierstrassZeta[ InverseWeierstrassP[0, {0, -w02}],
                               {0, -w02}] - 
               WeierstrassZeta[ x + InverseWeierstrassP[0, {0, -w02}],
                               {0, -w02}]),
        {x, -5/4, 5/4}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

This is the way to work more or less symbolically with elliptic functions.

Comment: Nicely done, and I fully concur with your first sentence.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. I've had to improve the earlier answer to make it more comprehensive.  I guess there should be a post collecting all no-go issues with elliptic functions, and I hope this is a step towards.

Answer (score 4):

**Comment**

You need to use the correct syntax for the built-in function `DSolve`.

Apart from this, `DSolve` is only able to give a general solution not a particular one.

```
Eq = f'''[x] + a*f'[x]^2 == 0

DSolve[{Eq}, f[x], x]
```

[image]

```
DSolve[{Eq, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}, f[x], x]
```

> DSolve::bvfail: For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions.

Only one condition can be utilized,

```
DSolve[{Eq, f[0] == 0}, f[x], x]
```

[image]

So, the other choice is to go for numerical solution if you are interested in, using `NDSolve`.

```
sol = NDSolve[{Eq /. {a -> 1}, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}, {f[x], f'[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]

Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], f'[x]} /. sol], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As above, you can use DSolve to find one constant but use Findroot to get the other constants, for a given a.

```
de = f'''[x] + a f'[x]^2 == 0;

DSolve[{de, f[0] == 0}, f[x], x];

% /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2};

f[x_] = (f[x] /. %[[1]]);

g[x_] = f'[x];
```

For example with a = 2;

```
FindRoot[{f[1] - 1, g[0]} /. a -> 2, {{c1, -5}, {c2, -5}}] // Chop

{c1->-3.8528,c2->-5.35369}

ff[x_] = f[x] /. % /. a -> 2

-(-1)^(1/3) 3^(2/3)*
(-WeierstrassZeta[(-(1/3))^(1/3) (x-3.8528), {0,-5.35369}]-(0.9053-1.56803 I))

{ff[0], ff[1], ff'[x] /. x -> 0} // Chop

{0,1.,0}
```

If you really want to satisfy your fourth condition f''[1]==1, you can do so
by also solving for a. You would then get for the constants:

```
{c1->-5.238,c2->-4.50964,a->0.867194}
```