# Finding the definite integral of a square root of a polynomial function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, polynomials

I am trying to find the arc length of the function:

f(x)=-0.005632x^7  + 0.08969x^6-0.5346x^5  + 1.364x^4  -0.8671x^3  -2.005x^2  + 3.038x + 0.4182

I am using this formula:

[image]

My boundaries are 0 and 5.

So, it boils down to calculating the following integral:
[image]

So, the integral of this function:

**1+(f'(x))^2 = (0.00155425x^12 - 0.0424313x^11 + 0.500355x^10 - 3.30709x^9 + 13.2222x^8 - 31.6513x^7 + 39.1191x^6 - 3.67819x^5 - 53.2315x^4 + 54.0131x^3 + 0.274601x^2 - 24.3648x + 10.23)^(1/2)**

I can't find a way to do so and programs like Wolfram Alpha or Mathway say that either the computing time is too long or the problem is unsolvable.

How should I go about it?
**Is there a way to integrate the square roots of polynomial functions?**

I don't think that the Differentiation under the integral sign works, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

**Or, is there another formula that could be used for finding the arc length?** I know there is another one for polar coordinates, but I don't know if it would help.

Comment: WolframAlpha [calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1%2BD%5B-0.005632+x%5E7+%2B+0.08969+x%5E6+-+0.5346+x%5E5+%2B+1.364+x%5E4+-+0.8671+x%5E3+-+2.005+x%5E2+%2B+3.038+x+%2B+0.4182%2C+x%5D%5E2%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+5%7D%5D+)

Comment: "Wolfram Alpha or Mathway say that either the computing time is too long or the problem is unsolvable."  what is Mathway?  There is a timelimit for Wolfram alpha. It looks you tried `Integrate` and not `NIntegrate`

Comment: In general we cannot expect symbolic results so far of calculations of such integrals. Read e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262996/transforming-implicit-solutions-of-an-ode-involving-inversefunction-to-an-explic/263003#263003). There is no genuine difficulty of numerical integration though.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Use `NIntegrate`

Answer (score 1):

As you can not do the integral symbolically, you need numerical integration.

Assume you want the arc length as a function in the range from a to b. For performance we calculate the derivative symbolically and we calculate the integral only from x to x+dx and then accumulate the values. This gives us a table of x and y values that we can interpolate.

For an example we choose a=0,b=1 and dx=0.01:

```
f[x_] = -0.005632 x^7 + 0.08969 x^6 - 0.5346 x^5 + 1.364 x^4 - 
   0.8671 x^3 - 2.005 x^2 + 3.038 x + 0.4182;
a = 0;
b = 1;
dx = 0.01;
deriv[x_] = Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2];
ys = Table[
   NIntegrate[deriv[x], {x, x0, x0 + dx}], {x0, a, b - dx, dx}];
PrependTo[ys, 0];
ys = Accumulate[ys];
xs = Table[x, {x, a, b, dx}];
arc = Interpolation[Transpose[{xs, ys}]];
Plot[arc[x], {x, a, b}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Small], Point[Transpose[{xs, ys}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = -0.005632 x^7 + 0.08969 x^6 - 0.5346 x^5 + 1.364 x^4 - 0.8671 x^3 - 
     2.005 x^2 + 3.038 x + 0.4182 // Rationalize // Simplify;
```

As mentioned in the comments, use [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)

```
l = NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + f'[x]^2], {x, 0, 5}]

(* 6.72629 *)
```

Or use the built-in function [`ArcLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html)

```
ArcLength[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(* 6.726291441 *)
```