# Solution of a BVP by Means of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, boundary-conditions, mathematica-online

If we consider the BVP $y^{\prime\prime}(t)=\frac{3}{2}y(t)^{2}$ where $0\leq t\leq1$ and $y(0)=4$ and $y(1)=1$. Then its solution is $y(t)=\frac{4}{(1+t)^{2}}$. I have set the BVP above as in mathemtica,

```
DSolve[{y''[t]==(3/2)(y[t])^2},y[0]==4,y[1]=1},y[x],x,0<= t <= 1]
```

When I run Mathemtica it says that DSolve::dsvar: $0\leq t\leq 1$ cannot be used as a variable.

Comment: There are 6 typos in one line of your code. Using `sol = DSolve[{y''[t] == (3/2) (y[t])^2}, y[t], t]`, we have out `{{y[t] -> 2^(2/3) WeierstrassP[(t + C[1])/2^(2/3), {0, C[2]}]}}`.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. To get started with Mathematica, please check out the [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor.

Comment: Dears, thanks for you help and suggesions. Please I have still issue in this equation solving. This example has been published in the paperhttps: //doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2018.02.016

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226353/how-to-solve-a-nonlinear-second-order-ode/226368#226368) you can find solution to a more general equation ( setting $a=0,\; b=0,\; c=3/2$ you obtain your equation.)  Symolically with `DSolve` one cannot solve BVP for this typ of ODE, however with a simple reasoning you can find the only one solution to the given problem.  Nevertheless you incorrectly put `0 <= t <=1`, one can evaluate e.g. `DSolve[{y''[t] == (3/2) y[t]^2}, y[t], {t, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: Does this solve your problem [How to solve a nonlinear second order ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226353/how-to-solve-a-nonlinear-second-order-ode). In fact this is a duplicate for the reason mentioned  above in my comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
SOL = DSolve[{y''[t] == (3/2) (y[t])^2}, y[t], t](*General solution*)

F = FindRoot[{(y[t] /. SOL[[1]] /. t -> 0 /. C[1] -> c1 /. 
    C[2] -> c2) == 4, (y[t] /. SOL[[1]] /. t -> 1 /. C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2) == 
  1}, {c1, 1/2}, {c2, 1/2}] // Chop // Rationalize
(*Finding constans c1 and c2*)

SOL /. C[1] -> c1 /. C[2] -> c2 /. F(*Paste constans c1 and c2 to general solution*)

(*{{y[t] -> 4/(1 + t)^2}}*)
```