# Problems with solutions involving Lambert W function of transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions, special-functions

`Solve` and `Reduce` fail here with rational parameter `l`, but succeed when I plug in a value

```
Assuming[ l ∈ Rationals && l > 0, 
  Solve[x  Exp[-2/(x)] == (x - 1) - 1 /(2 l), x, Reals]]

% /. l -> 15/31
```

> ```
> {{x -> 122/(60 + 61 ProductLog[-1, -60/(61 E^(60/61))])}}
> ```

Can I coax her to produce an answer which depends on the parameter?
It turns out the equation can be solved by a series of  substitutions, yielding
$$x=\frac{d}{f + W_L(- f e^{-f})},\; d= 7- 2 l,\; f= \frac{2d\;l}{2 l+1}$$

It should be possible to convince Mathematica do release me from this chore :)

**Edit two hours later:)** Thanks for previous answers, but I'm still missing something. I found from papers like [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf)  that I can reduce my equation to a canonic form

```
eq = (z - f) Exp[z] == -f
```

It is now a trivial case which can be solved by substitution $z-f=y$, but I want *Mathematica* to do all work.

```
Solve[eq, z, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0, z, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0 && z ∈ Reals, z, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0 && z ∈ Reals && f ∈ Reals, z, 
 Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0, z, Method -> Reduce] /. C[1] -> 0
```

First Solve gets all cases; second removes some, but I still have the branch chooser C[1]. third time I say I want real roots, and I am reminded that f maybe complex. forth time I get an error

```
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.
```

So, fifth time I give up, erase the two last assumptions, and decide to "talk simple" to  *Mathematica*  with `C[1] -> 0`  OK...

Still, it is a pity that  `f ∈ Reals`  did not succed, like it does
when I choose `f` from the start

```
    Solve[(eq /. f -> 5/2) && z != 0 && z ∈ Reals, z, Method -> Reduce]
```

Comment: The solution is `x == 2/((4 l)/(2 l + 1) + ProductLog[-1, -((4 l)/(1 + 2 l)) E^(-((4 l)/(1 + 2 l)))])` but I cannot coax Mathematica to yield it either.

Comment: Note that the assumptions are not used in your code since `Solve` does not use the option `Assumptions`. The assumptions should be included in the `Solve` as constraints. In cases where `Solve` produces a result (which it does not here), including `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` in the `Assuming` would then make use of the assumptions.

Comment: There are several issues when solving equations symbolically, and one has to do some experimental work. Don't expect you will obtain results strictly from scratch to the point you want. This is not possible now nethier in future will be.  Unless there is a well defined goal to achieve. Now I cannot see what you really expect. Examine carefully  [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129) or if you make your statement more prcecise I will point out another helpful post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve with the Method->Reduce is actually Reduce.

a) the built-in does not work with the restriction x in `Reals`.
b) the built-in does not work with the restriction l positive.
c) the formulation variation between `Assumption` and `&&`-logic is just to prefer the recommendation in the documentation of `Solve`.

```
ClearAll[x, ll]
Solve[x Exp[-2/(x)] == (x - 1) - 1/(2 ll) && 
  Element[ll, Rationals], x, Method -> Reduce]
```

---

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[-(I/(2 \[Pi] C[1])), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && ll == -(1/2)]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[1/(I \[Pi] + 2 I \[Pi] C[1]), 
    C[1] \[Element] Integers && ll == -(1/2)]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(2 (1 + 2 ll))/(
    4 ll + ProductLog[C[
      1], -((4 E^(-((4 ll)/(1 + 2 ll))) ll)/(1 + 2 ll))] + 
     2 ll ProductLog[C[
       1], -((4 E^(-((4 ll)/(1 + 2 ll))) ll)/(1 + 2 ll))]), 
    ll \[Element] Rationals]}}
```

And the substitution:

```
% /. ll -> 15/31
```

---

```
{{x -> Undefined}, {x -> Undefined}, {x -> 122/(
   31 (60/31 + 61/31 ProductLog[C[1], -(60/(61 E^(60/61)))]))}}
```

This result is different. There is a free c1 parameter.

```
Solve[eq, z, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0, z, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0 && Element[z, Reals], z, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0, z, Reals, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0 && Element[z, Reals] && Element[f, Reals], z, 
 Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0 && Element[f, Reals], z, Reals, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0, {z, f}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]
Solve[eq && z != 0, z, Method -> Reduce] /. C[1] -> 0
```

[image: results]
Solve prefers the condition of the domain in the later argument list and not in the logics of the equations set.
Solve prefers more freedom to restrictions. The more general the solution defined in the equations is the better the results.
The option `Method->Reduce` employs actually the built-in `Reduce` instead of `Solve`.

I created some inputs for examples. My outputs are different. I use V12.0.0.

Comment: @Steppen Jaeschke Thanks for the comments. Could I have your input examples? The outputs do not matter since I had anyway a more general equation, which I solved by hand (using substitutions). As an interesting Mathematica problem, the more general problems in the article arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3999.pdf cannot be solved by us by hand, but they should be a fair task for Mathematica

Answer (score 5):

Both `Reduce` and `Solve` do what they should (see e.g. [What is the difference between Reduce and Solve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17127/what-is-the-difference-between-reduce-and-solve/17129#17129)) even though they might be always better. `Reduce` may deal with various transcendental functions, however it is not refined enough to work e.g. with elliptic functions, see e.g. [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158654/problem-solving-third-order-non-linear-differential-equation-in-mathematica/158663#158663) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164927/optimization-of-ode-with-respect-to-the-initial-condition/164949#164949). Nevertheless it works well here yielding a bit involved result (we use `y` instead of `l` to avoid possible confusion with `1`):

```
Reduce[x  Exp[-2/(x)] == (x - 1) - 1/(2y), x] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

We can find out that for any $0\leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$ solution is complex.
However one observes that it might work here, although it doesn't

```
Solve[ x  Exp[-2/(x)] == (x - 1) - 1 /(2y) && (y > 0 && y != 1/2) && x ∈ Reals,
       x, MaxExtraConditions->All]
```

since the output is expected to be real and unique, see

```
Plot[ ReIm[1/(-2x Exp[-2/x]+ 2x - 2)], {x, -4, 4}, Evaluated -> True,
      PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotRange-> {-3,3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
      Epilog->{ Dashed, Thick, Red, Line[{{1.255,-3},{1.255,3}}],  
                Cyan, Line[{{-4,1/2},{4,1/2}}]}]
```

[image]

On the other hand one might make `Solve` yield slightly restricted result with `Method -> Reduce`, e.g.:

```
sol = FullSimplify[ x/. First @ Solve[ x Exp[-2/(x)] == (x - 1) - 1/(2y), x,
                     Method -> Reduce] /. C[1] -> 0]
```

> ```
> (2 + 4y)/(4y + (1 + 2y) ProductLog[-4y/(E^((4y)/(1 + 2y)) (1 + 2y))])
> ```

```
ay = Limit[ sol, y -> -Infinity]
N @ %
```

> ```
> 2/(2 + ProductLog[-2/E^2])
> 1.255
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
eqn = x Exp[-2/(x)] == (x - 1) - 1/(2 l);
```

Let `x == 2/y && y != 0`

```
eqn2 = eqn /. x -> 2/y // FullSimplify[#, y != 0] &

(* 4 + E^y (-4 + (2 + 1/l) y) == 0 *)

soly = Assuming[l > 0 && y != 0, 
  Solve[eqn2 && y != 0, y, Method -> Reduce][[1]] // Simplify]
```

[image]

Verifying that this satisfies `eqn2`

```
eqn2 /. soly // Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &

(* True *)
```

The solution for `x` is then

```
solx = (x -> 2/y) /. soly
```

[image]

```
eqn /. solx // Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &

(* True *)
```

For `C[1]  ==  -1` this is the same result as that provided by Roman in his comment.

**EDIT:**

Real solutions require that `C[1]` be either `-1` or `0`

```
fd = FunctionDomain[{x /. solx, Element[C[1], Integers]}, l] // 
  Simplify[#, Element[C[1], Integers]] &
```

[image]

Comment: It appears that you've provided (almost) an equivalent  answer.