# Optimization of ODE with respect to the initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization, special-functions

One has a (system) of ODEs with a one-parameter family of initial conditions. For example,

```
f[kk_] := N[aa = kk; s = NDSolve[{y''[t] == y[t]^2, y[1] == aa, y'[1] == 1},
                                  y, {t, 2}]; Evaluate[(y[2] /. s)][[1]]]
```

where `k` is the parameter, and one sees $f(k)$ as a function of $k$  works fine, as one can try to plot

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 0}]
```

and obtain

[image]

However, when one tries to find the min, using `FindMinimum` or `NMinimize`, it does not work as it seems *Mathematica* would first perform symbolic calculation with

```
NDSolve[{(y''[t] == -2y[t], y[1] == x, y'[1] == 1}, y, {t, 2}]
```

which results an error as the initial condition is not a number, and returns `y[2.]` before continuing evaluating `NMinimize[y[2.], x]`.

Does anyone know how to get around it, or some better ways to do the optimization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve) or it's cousin [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue):

```
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {y''[t] == y[t]^2, y[1] == aa, y'[1] == 1},
    y[2],
    {t, 2},
    aa
];

NMinimize[s[aa], aa]
```

> {0.0964433, {aa -> -1.65429}}

Answer (score 9):

Harnessing symbolic functionality one can get a glimpse of **beauty** of the **mathematical world** and a quantum of deeper **understanding**, therefore often it is of high importance and preferable to exploit symbolic rather than numeric tools, even though in certain cases the latter would yield more. Thus  it is a reasonable practice to put forward exact methods and use approximate ones only if symbolic functionality fails.

We'll demonstrate that the function to be minimized is quite involved 
$$y(t,a)=6\;\wp\bigg(t-1+\wp^{-1}\Big(\frac{a}{6};\;0,\frac{a^3}{54}-\frac{1}{36}\Big);\;0,\frac{a^3}{54}-\frac{1}{36}\bigg)$$
where $\wp$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function and it can be done with `NMinimize` as well as with `FindMinimum`,  however getting the actual result involves some insight into the matter because of suboptimal handling of elliptic functions and integrals in *Mathematica* (a marvelous [trademark](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23117#23117) figured out by J.M.). Encountering this issue wherever below one will be warned with  this sign $**$.

Let's start with a few quite natural observations. Having equations of the form `y''[t] == y[t]^2` it is a good idea to multiply it by `y'[t]` and integrate it once using initial (boundary) conditions.
$0=y''(t)-y(t)^2\; $  thus $\;0=y'(t) y''(t)-y(t)^2 y'(t)\;$ i.e. $\;0=1/2 \;y'(t)^2 -1/3\; y(t)^3 +c$ and using initial conditions we find:  $\;c=-1/2 + a^3/3 $. Rewriting $\;y(t)=6 w(t)$ one obtains:
$$w'(t)^2-4w(t)^3+ \frac{a^3}{54} - \frac{1}{36}=0$$ 
This is a standard form of a differential equation for the Weierstrass elliptic function $w'(t)^2-4w(t)^3+ g_2 w(t)+g_3=0\;$ with $\;g_2=0$ and $g_3= \frac{a^3}{54} - \frac{1}{36}$.
*Mathematica* can $**$ solve  this more general form on the symbolic level without specifying initial conditions:

```
w[t]/. DSolve[ w'[t]^2 - 4 w[t]^3 + g2 w[t] + g3 == 0, w[t], t]
```

> ```
> { WeierstrassP[ t - C[1], {g2, g3}], WeierstrassP[ t + C[1], {g2, g3}]}
> ```

however one might be misled using it $**$ with $g_2=0$.

Now, using once more the initial conditions we find

`C[1] == 1 - InverseWeierstrassP[ a/6, {0, a^3/54 - 1/36}]` and finally:

```
y[t_, a_] := 6 WeierstrassP[ t - 1 + InverseWeierstrassP[ a/6, {0, a^3/54 - 1/36}],
                             {0, a^3/54 - 1/36}]
```

when plotting this function $**$ one uses `Re[ y[2,a]]` rather than `y[2,a]` alone, since the latter produces $**$ some nonvanishing imaginary perturbations.

```
Plot[ Re @ y[2, a], {a, -3, 0}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

$**$ `Minimize[{y[2, a], -3 < a < 0}, a]` doesn't work, however $**$ `NMinimize[{ Re @ y[2, a], -3 < a < 0}, a]` works fine and alternatively an excellent approximation $**$ with `FindMinimum` as you liked can be found:

```
FindMinimum[ Re @ y[2, a], {a, 0}] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {0.0964433, {a -> -1.65429}}
> ```

If we'd like studying **full complexity** of the function `y`, a useful tool might be e.g.

```
Manipulate[ Plot[ Re @ y[t, a], {a, -10, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
           {t, -30, 30}]
```

which wouldn't be readily available with a numerical approach.

Another nice application and  a bit more detailed explanation of a few issues related to elliptic functions one can find in e.g. [Integrate yields complex value, while after variable transformation the result is real. Bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrate-yields-complex-value-while-after-variable-transformation-the-result-i/160055#160055). Elliptic functions are solutions to certain nonlinear ordinary differential equations and being implemented in ***Mathematica 1.0*** they might be slightly revised, although some useful functionality like `WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1` is implemented also in verion ***11.2***.

Comment: Very nice; I really wish elliptic functions can be more gracefully handled someday.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks,  nice to see you back at MSE.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple fix for your problem is to prevent `f` from evaluating without numeric arguments. While I'm at it, I'll also rewrite `f` in a slightly nicer way:

```
Clear[f];
f[kk_?NumericQ] := Module[{sol, y},
  sol = First[
    N[NDSolve[{y''[t] == y[t]^2, y[1] == kk, y'[1] == 1}, y, {t, 2}]]
  ];
  y[2] /. sol
];
```

The `_?NumericQ` pattern on `f` prevents the function from evaluating symbolically. In this form, `NMinimize` and `FindMinimum` work immediately:

```
NMinimize[f[x], x]
FindMinimum[f[x], {x, 0}]
```

Finally, I'd like to point out that your use of `Evaluate` does nothing in your code. `Evaluate` is used to override a `Hold` attribute. For example:

```
Hold[Range[3], Evaluate[Range[3]]]
```