# Function with EllipticK does not evaluate in certain range

Tags: special-functions

I have some rather complicated function (related to the capacitance of coplanar waveguides for specific geometric parameters, for those who are interested) which I've trimmed down to the following for simplicity:

```
SampleFun[w_, s_, g_, h2_] := Module[{a, b, c0, k2, k2p, k4, k4p, q2},
  a = s/2;
  b = s/2 + w;
  c0 = g + w + s/2;
  k2 = a/b*Sqrt[(1 - b^2/c0^2)/(1 - a^2/c0^2)];
  k2p = Sqrt[1 - k2^2];
  k4 = Sinh[Pi*a/2/h2]/Sinh[Pi*b/2/h2]*
    Sqrt[(1 - Sinh[Pi*b/2/h2]^2/Sinh[Pi*c0/2/h2]^2)/(
     1 - Sinh[Pi*a/2/h2]^2/Sinh[Pi*c0/2/h2]^2)];
  k4p = Sqrt[1 - k4^2];
  q2 = EllipticK[k4]/EllipticK[k4p]*1/2*EllipticK[k2p]/EllipticK[k2];
  Return[q2]]
```

The source of the equation is a combination of theory found in [Gevorgian et al (1995)](https://doi.org/10.1109/22.375223) (fairly legible) and [Garg et al (1979)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1608075354) around [p. 376](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=1PQfAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA376). In its entire form it will give the capacitance per unit length of a coplanar waveguide resonator with finite ground planes and a double layered substrate of finite thicknesses.

Now, since this function depends sensitively on the geometric input parameters, lets say that we can always take `w = 1500*10^-9`, `s = 30*10^-6`, `g = 50*10^-6`, and `h2` is a number that goes from `0` (lets take `0.1*10^-9` as we can't divide by 0) to `400*10^-9` for the range that I am interested in.

If we look at the function in this range, then it behaves in a peculiar way; for low values there seems to be an error in the calculation, and it gives exactly 0.

[image: bad plot]

Does anyone understand what is going on here, and how I could go about fixing it? I believe the problem stems from the `EllipticK[k4p]` part, as the rest seems to evaluate nicely, but it might be a combination of factors so I didn't leave out more. It is quite problematic for my calculation, as `h2` is approximately `100*10^-9` in the geometry I am considering, which falls exactly in this gap.

Note, this is for *Mathematica* 10.0.2, which now that I write it I should definitely update as it might be something that is fixed in future versions.

Comment: Look at similar issues, e.g. [Optimization of ODE with respect to the initial condition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164927/optimization-of-ode-with-respect-to-the-initial-condition/164949#164949).  Elliptic functions may produce some imaginary perturbations for certain ranges of arguments where they should be real-valued. Then one should use e.g. `Re`. Nonetheless I find you've defined your function in a suboptimal  way.

Comment: Simply use higher workingprecision  `Plot[SampleFun[1500 10^-9, 30 10^-6, 100 10^-3, x 10^-9], {x, 1, 500},
  WorkingPrecision -> 25] `

Comment: Using Re brings me to the internal precision limit however, and using Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000},..] doesn't solve that either. Moreover, WorkingPrecision in the plot is giving me that the precision of the argument function is less than 25.

Comment: Looking at it more closely, I believe that k4p is very close to 1, which is what the function has trouble with. So I should probably repose the question as being how to evaluate the EllipticK very close to 1. I could do a series expansion, but the value won't always be close to 1..

Comment: @user129412 When evaluating your function the system didn't work correctly so I guess it might be  improved, I haven't my computer at the moment so I cannot provide a better function.

Comment: After confirmation, I will now need to rap your knuckles: *please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other users have confirmed your observations to be a bug*.

Comment: You're absolutely right, @J.M. I apologise, I'm not sure why I chose that.

Comment: Just edit your post to include the source for your formula, and we're cool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is unfortunate that the OP neglected to give a source for the formula (always give references if providing an unfamiliar formula!) in the question; I will nevertheless proceed with my guess, based on a cursory look at the provided code.

The heart of the issue seems to be about the OP neglecting to check if his/her preferred convention for elliptic integrals matches with *Mathematica*'s preferred convention. I have ranted about this in [this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659), but suffice it to say that the OP's formula seems to be assuming the modulus $k$ to be the argument, while `EllipticK[]` needs the parameter $m$ as an argument.

Thus:

```
SampleFun[w_, s_, g_, h2_] := Module[{a, b, c0, m2, m2p, m4, m4p},
      a = s/2; b = s/2 + w; c0 = g + w + s/2;
      m2 = (a/b)^2 (1 - b^2/c0^2)/(1 - a^2/c0^2);
      m2p = 1 - m2;
      m4 = (Sinh[π a/2/h2]/Sinh[π b/2/h2])^2
           (1 - Sinh[π b/2/h2]^2/Sinh[π c0/2/h2]^2)/
           (1 - Sinh[π a/2/h2]^2/Sinh[π c0/2/h2]^2);
      m4p = 1 - m4;
      EllipticK[m4]/EllipticK[m4p]*1/2*EllipticK[m2p]/EllipticK[m2]]

Plot[SampleFun[15*^-7, 3*^-5, 1/10, x 1*^-9], {x, 1, 500}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: plot]

---

Here is the long-overdue follow-through. The key insight here is that one can use the [relationship between the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and the arithmetic-geometric mean](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticK/26/03/04/0001/), after which one can then use the [homogeneity relation for the AGM](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/ArithmeticGeometricMean/16/01/01/0003/) to stave off cancellations and bad scaling. Applying this to the specific problem here, we have the following stabilized routine:

```
SampleFun[w_, s_, g_, h2_] := Module[{a, b, c0, ab, ac0, bc0, sab, sac0, sbc0},
      a = s/2; b = s/2 + w; c0 = g + w + s/2;
      ab = a/b; ac0 = 1 - (a/c0)^2; bc0 = 1 - (b/c0)^2;
      sab = Sinh[π a/2/h2]/Sinh[π b/2/h2];
      sac0 = 1 - (Sinh[π a/2/h2]/Sinh[π c0/2/h2])^2;
      sbc0 = 1 - (Sinh[π b/2/h2]/Sinh[π c0/2/h2])^2;

      1/2 * ArithmeticGeometricMean[Sqrt[sac0], sab Sqrt[sbc0]]/
      ArithmeticGeometricMean[Sqrt[sac0], Sqrt[sac0 - sab^2 sbc0]] *
      ArithmeticGeometricMean[Sqrt[ac0], Sqrt[ac0 - ab^2 bc0]]/
      ArithmeticGeometricMean[Sqrt[ac0], ab Sqrt[bc0]]]
```

which is now much less prone to subtractive cancellation or overflow than the previous version. (Try using it in the `Plot[]` command above without the `WorkingPrecision` option set.)

Comment: Based on your math.SE post and and the literature, I indeed agree that I made a mistake in using the parameter m instead of the modulus k. Even with that fix though, one still requires WorkingPrecision -> 30 to get the plotting to work. What would be the best way to have the formula give output by itself? Use something like N[m4p, 30]?

Comment: It's backwards; *Mathematica* needs the parameter, while your references use the modulus. Yes, the `WorkingPrecision -> 30` is a bit of a crutch; I have an idea on how to stabilize the formula, but you'll have to wait a while, since I'm in the middle of moving to a new place.

Comment: That is perfectly fine for me, I'd be very interested once youre settled and have some time. For now, this will do though, I can finish my design!

Comment: I'd still be interested, if you could find the time at some point. Hope moving was smooth!

Comment: Apologies for the much delayed response; please have a look now.

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you.