# Smallest positive real solution with InverseWeierstrassP

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

How can I get the smallest positive real solution with 
`InverseWeierstrassP[p, {g2, g3}]` for real $g_2, g_3$ (if it exists)?

The documentation just says, that the function gives **a**  values of $u$ for which the Weierstrass function $\wp(u,g_2,g_3)$ is equal to $p$.

In many cases it suffices to take the absolute value, e.g. for

```
N[InverseWeierstrassP[2, {0, 1}], 20])] = -0.70870542625436725012.
```

But for `N[InverseWeierstrassP[-1/2, {1, -1}], 20]` the output is
$0.4503458373984861376 + 1.4343014857897211158 i\ $
although I would like to have $2.379880191665208495\dots$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculate the inverse using [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
iwp = u /. 
  FindRoot[WeierstrassP[u, {1, -1}] == -1/2, {u, 1/10}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* 2.3798801916652084955 *)
```

Verifying,

```
WeierstrassP[iwp, {1, -1}] // Chop[#, 10^-16] &

(* -0.5000000000000000 *)
```

[`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) removes an imaginary artifact caused by use of inexact numbers.

Answer (score 7):

**Elliptic functions**

Instead of playing with numerical solvers, we can exploit a canonical exact approach. Since the Weierstrass elliptic function $\wp$ is doubly periodic (as every elliptic function), taking an inverse of it makes sense only locally and so some kind of arbitrariness is inevitable, otherwise we would get an infinite lattice of points $\wp^{-1}(\frac{1}{2};1,-1)$,  see e.g. (  [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrating-a-real-function-i-get-a-complex-value-while-after-variable-transfor/160055#160055), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221026/solving-equations-involving-integrals/221062#221062)). Double periodicity means that $\wp$ is defined on a fundamental parallelogram and with help of periods we can extend its definition on the whole complex plane. This implies also by the Liouville theorem that in every parallelogram there must be a singularity.

Let's find periods of $\wp$ by the Weierstrass half-periods:

```
{p1, p2, p3} = 2 Through @ { WeierstrassHalfPeriodW1, 
                             WeierstrassHalfPeriodW2, WeierstrassHalfPeriodW3} @ {1, -1};
```

**Double argument of $\wp^{-1}$**

There is a double argument in `InverseWeierstrassP`, namely a pair $(p,q)$ such that $$\;q^2-4p^3+g_2\; p+g_3=0$$ This is a basic **ODE** satisfied by $\wp$, where $p=\wp(x;g_2,g_3)\;$ and $q=\wp'(x,g_2,g_3)$.

```
Solve[q^2 - 4 (-1/2)^3 + (-1/2) - 1 == 0, q]
```

> ```
> {{ q -> -1}, { q -> 1}}
> ```

and finally a symbolic solution reads `InverseWeierstrassP[{-(1/2), -1}, {1, -1}] - p1`, which can be evaluated with arbitrary precission, e.g.:

```
InverseWeierstrassP[{-(1/2), -1}, {1, -1}] - p1 // N[#, 50] & // Chop
```

> ```
> 2.3798801916652084954875662184452287387253505855238
> ```

The both solutions for two different $q$ in the fundamental paralellogram spanned by two of three vectors of $p_1, p_2, p_3$:

```
pts = ReIm[ InverseWeierstrassP[{-(1/2), #}, {1, -1}] & /@ {1, -1} 
            - p1 // N // Chop]
```

> ```
> {{0.450346, 1.4343}, {2.37988, 0}}
> ```

**Graphical representation**

To illustrate the basic concepts we'll add a plot. Although there is quite versatile `ComplexPlot` I prefer more involved construction with `ContourPlot` to achieve clearer explanation of all those auxiliary functions related to elliptic functions.

```
f[x_, y_] := WeierstrassP[x + I y, {1, -1}]
{v1, v2, v3} = ReIm @ {p1, p2, p3} // N;
Show[  
  ContourPlot[ Re[f[x, y]], {x, -1, 7}, {y, -4, 4},
    ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", Contours -> 10], 
  ContourPlot[{Re[f[x, y]] == -1/2, Im[f[x, y]] == 0, Re[f[x, y]] == 0,
    Im[f[x, y]] == -1/2}, {x, -1, 7}, {y, -4, 4}, Evaluated -> True, 
    ContourStyle -> {{Thick, Cyan}, {Thick, Magenta}, {Dashed, Red},
                     {Dotted, Yellow}}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Below], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    PlotPoints -> 80, MaxRecursion -> 5],
  Graphics[{ Arrowheads[Large], Thick, Lighter @ Orange, 
             Arrow[{v3, v3 + v2}], Arrow[{v3 + v2, v3 + v1 + v2}],
             Arrow[{v3 + v1 + v2, v3}], Red, PointSize[0.025], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

The orange arrows denote periods of $\wp$, only two of them are linearly independent since $p_1 +p_2 + p_3=0$.  Points where cyan curves and magenta lines intersect (outside centers of quatrefoil patterns, since therein are singularities) are solutions $\wp(x; 1,-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$. Two solutions in the chosen paralellogram are denoted by red points.