# First order Differential equation with boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, symbolic, boundary-conditions

I'm wondering why it is not solving with the Mathematica??

```
Clear["Global`*"]
DSolve[{(y'[x])^2 == a*y[x] - (k*y[x]^2) + ((f*y[x]^4)/3), y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

If you can find anyway to plot it for the some value for a,k and f?
thank you

Comment: A solution will be expressed in terms of elliptic functions.  You can solve it implicitly without boundary condition or transform the equation into Weierstrass canonical form see [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172343/smallest-positive-real-solution-with-inverseweierstrassp/271745#271745), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274859/a-fraught-with-incorrect-results-ode/275048#275048), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214063/the-time-like-geodesics-orbits-in-the-schwarzschild-spacetime/214076#214076)... and then include the condition.

Comment: Are you seeking Real solutions only?

Answer (score 3):

I just solved it without you boundary condition:

```
 Clear["Global`*"]
 eqns2 = {g'[x]^2 == a (f/3 g[x]^3 + 1 - k/a g[x]) g[x]};
 sol2 = DSolve[eqns2, g[x], x]
```

Comment: Could you plot it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Plots can be obtained as follows.    First, solve the ODE without the boundary condition.

```
sol = DSolve[{(y'[x])^2 == a*y[x] - (k*y[x]^2) + ((f*y[x]^4)/3)}, [x], x]
```

The solution is too lengthy to reproduce here but has the form,

```
{Solve[exp == x/Sqrt[3] + C[1], Solve[exp == -x/Sqrt[3] + C[1]}
```

where the lengthy expression `exp` is the same for both solutions.  However, `C[1]` is not necessarily the same for both.  Let us focus on the first solution.  The constant of integration, `C[1]` is obtained from

```
sol[[1, 1]] /. x -> 1 /. y[1] -> 1;
c = FullSimplify[%] // First;
```

which also is rather lengthy.  Now construct with, for instance, `{a -> 1, f -> 1, k -> 1}`,

```
arg = N@SolveValues[sol[[1, 1]] /. {y[x] -> w, C[1] -> c} /. {a -> 1, f -> 1, 
     k -> 1}, x] // First // Simplify;
```

which again is lengthy but can be plotted without difficulty.  (Note that `y[x]` is replaced by `w` for convenience.

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[{Chop[arg], w}, {w, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {x, "y[x]"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

To obtain the second half of this curve, note that it simply is the first half, just plotted, reflected in `x` about the point where `w = 0`.

```
Chop[arg /. w -> 10^-12]
(* 3.48209 *)
```

So, the total solution is

```
p2 = ParametricPlot[{2 3.48209 - Chop[arg], w}, {w, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {x, "y[x]"}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}];
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 8}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

By the symmetry already noted of the two solutions contained in `sol`, the second curve passing through `y[1] = 1` is identical to the plot immediately above but centered at `x = -1.48209` instead of `x = 3.48209`.

Incidentally, it is simpler but not quite as accurate to use `NDSolve` to obtain one of the two branches and, once again, adding the second branch by reflecting the first about the value of `x` for which `y[x] = 0`.

**Addendum**

A still simpler approach for a symbolic solution is to determine `x` directly as a function of `y`, including the boundary condition.

```
solx = DSolve[{x'[y]^2 (a*y - k*y^2 + f*y^4/3) == 1, x[1] == 1}, 
    x[y], y] // Values // Flatten
```

which then can be plotted with `ParametricPlot` as above.

```
argx = solx /. {a -> 1, f -> 1, k -> 1};
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Thread[{argx, y}], {y, 0, 4}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A completely numerical solution can be obtained quite simply as follows.  With

```
eq = y'[x]^2 == a*y[x] - k*y[x]^2 + f*y[x]^4/3
```

differentiate `eq` and eliminate common terms to obtain a second order autonomous ODE.

```
D[eq, x];
eqlin = DivideSides[%, 2 y'[x], Assumptions -> y'[x] != 0] // Cancel
(* (y''[x] == 1/6 (3 a - 6 k y[x] + 4 f y[x]^3) *)
```

The two corresponding initial conditions are

```
y[1] == 1

eq /. x -> 1 /. y[1] -> 1
(* y'[1]^2 == a + f/3 - k *)
```

If real solutions are required, as seems likely, then a + f/3 - k > 0 is necessary.  For the parameters used in my earlier, symbolic solution,

```
Quiet@NDSolve[{eqlin, y[1] == 1, y'[1]^2 == a - k + f/3} /. {a -> 1, 
    f -> 1, k -> 1}, y[x], {x, -10, 10}] // Flatten // Values;
Join[{x}, Interval @@ Flatten[% /. x -> "Domain", 1] // First]
Quiet@Plot[%%, %, AxesLabel -> {x, "y[x]"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

as expected.  In general, curves are bounded from above by the smallest root greater than `1` of,

```
a*y - k*y^2 + f*y^4/3 == 0
```

if any.  Otherwise, the curves are unbounded from above, as in the plot above.  Similarly, the curves are bounded from below by the largest root less than `1`.  Note that `y == 0` always is a root.  Here is an example of a solution bounded from both above and below.

```
FindInstance[{a - k*y + f*y^3/3 == 0, y > 1, a + f/3 - k > 0}, {a, f, k, y}] 
    // N // Flatten;
param = % // Most
(* {a -> 0.887756, f -> -4.88266, k -> -2.21939} *)

Quiet@NDSolve[{eqlin, y[1] == 1, y'[1]^2 == a - k + f/3} /. param, 
    y[x], {x, -10, 10}] // Flatten // Values;
Join[{x}, Interval @@ Flatten[% /. x -> "Domain", 1] // First];
Quiet@Plot[%%, %, AxesLabel -> {x, "y[x]"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.4}]
```

[image]