# How to simplify this formula?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, symbolic, special-functions

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 x^3}} \, dx
$$

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - 2 x^3], x]// FullSimplify
```

The result is very complex.

Then I want to differentiate it with the operator `D`.

```
% // D[#, x] & // FullSimplify
```

but I didn't get what I want.

How to add conditions to get origin formula?

Meanwhile, using `Rubi` can do it.

[image]

> My Mathematica version is 11.3, and seems that in 12.0 , this question has been solved.

Comment: *Mathematica*'s elliptic integral results tend to be more complicated than necessary. Nevertheless, using the results from [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/33500), you have the expression `InverseJacobiCN[(2 Sqrt[3])/(1 + Sqrt[3] - x 2^(1/3)) - 1, (2 + Sqrt[3])/4]/(2^(1/3) 3^(1/4))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the function `x Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, 2 x^3]`   can be obtained by integration of the integrand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x^3}}$ in `Mathematica 12` as observed by   Bob Hanlon, it cannot be obtained in `Mathematica 11.2` and earlier versions, even though `D[x Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, 2 x^3],x]` yields $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x^3}}$ also in version `11.2`. On the other hand J.M. observed that the integral can be expressed in terms of the elliptic integrals. This integral can be simply reformulated by the definition of the Weierstras elliptic function (see e.g.  [Integrate yields complex value, while after variable transformation the result is real. Bug?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrate-yields-complex-value-while-after-variable-transformation-the-result-i/160055#160055))

Recalling the linked post one can write (mind **appropriate limits of integration** and **constants** which can be complex in general):
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 x^3}} \, dx =  \int_{\infty}^{x} \frac{i \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{4 t^3-2}}\,dt=i \sqrt{2}\; \wp^{-1}(x;0,2)
$$
where $\wp$ in the Weierstrass elliptic function, while $\wp^{-1}$ is its inverse function implemented in the Wolfram Language as `InverseWeierstrassP`. This formula can be used **only in appropriate regions** of the real axis or the complex plane, as well as that given by `x Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, 2 x^3]` and the **proper regions are different** for the both expressions, signalizing that thay can be used in different cases. However as observed elsewhere (see e.g. answers to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent)) the ellliptic integrals and functions where  implemented in a suboptimal way at least until version `11.2` and and to demonstrate symbolically 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 x^3}}=i \sqrt{2}\; \frac{d}{dx}\wp^{-1}(x;0,2)$$
is difficult at least before version `12`. Nonetheless we can do e.g.

```
FullSimplify[D[I Sqrt[2] InverseWeierstrassP[x, {0, 2}], x]]
```

> ```
> (I Sqrt[2])/WeierstrassPPrime[InverseWeierstrassP[x, {0, 2}], {0, 2}]
> ```

i.e. acting with `TraditionalForm` yields  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2 x^3}}=i \sqrt{2}\; \frac{d}{dx}\wp^{-1}(x;0,2)= \frac{i \sqrt{2}}{\wp'(\wp^{-1}(x;0,2);0,2)}=f(x)$$
we can also demonstrate this equality for numbers such that $1-2x^3>0$, e.g. define

```
f[x_] := (I Sqrt[2])/ WeierstrassPPrime[InverseWeierstrassP[x, {0, 2}], {0, 2}]

And @@ Table[
         FullSimplify[f[x] == 1/Sqrt[1 - 2 x^3]],
         {x, {2/3, 3/5, 13/20, 13/19, 5/7, 7/12, 15/23, 1/Sqrt[2],
              1/Sqrt[3], 1/Pi, 1/E, Sqrt[3]/Pi}}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

and plot the both functions, one is shifted by $1/20$ for a better presentation

```
Plot[{f[x], 1/Sqrt[1 - 2 x^3] - 1/20}, {x, -1, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

This demonstrates certain flavours of equality of the both functions and I hope it makes clear what can be done in `Mathematica` on the symbolic level.

Comment: Alternatively, if you make the substitution $x=-\sqrt[3]{2}u$, you can obtain another (equivalent) Weierstrassian integral: `-2^(1/3) InverseWeierstrassP[-(x/2^(1/3)), {0, -1}]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your remark. Indeed, this can be a helpful, however in our case I find my approach easier to handle.

Answer (score 6):

Works well in version 12

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

int = Integrate[1/Sqrt[1 - 2 x^3], x]

(* x Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, 2 x^3] *)
```

The derivative returns the original expression

```
D[int, x]

(* 1/Sqrt[1 - 2 x^3] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the replacement `u=x^3`. Then `dx=du/3u^2/3`and

```
Integrate[1/3 u^(-2/3)/Sqrt[1 - 2 u], u] /. u -> x^3
```

yields

```
(* (x^3)^(1/3) Hypergeometric2F1[1/3, 1/2, 4/3, 2 x^3]  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: it gives out $\frac{B_{2 x^3}\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}\right)}{3 \sqrt[3]{2}}$ which is also very nice, thx.