# Get a symbolic solution from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, physics

My input is

```
DSolve[{s''[t] == g Sin[θ], s[0] == 0, 
  s'[t]^2 == 2 g l Cos[θ]}, s[t], t]
```

I will get a pop-up

> DSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables than equations,
>   so the system is overdetermined.

*After searching the internet, I find the only way to solve this is setting `g,l,θ` numeric values and  use `DSolveValue`, but I want a symbolic function without `C[1], C[2]`.

A pic to illustrate this idea.
[image]

I wan to get the output like this

```
 s[t] -> 1/2 (g t^2 Sin[θ] + 2 t (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] Sqrt[Cos[θ]] - g t Sin[θ]))
```

Comment: Second IC should maybe be something like this. `s'[0] == Sqrt[2 g l Cos[\[Theta]]]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I believe   ``s'[0]==0``.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  the starting point is `\[Theta]=Pi/2`

Comment: Point being, you cannot specify both `s'[t]' and `s''[t]` unless they are compatible. As written in the post, they are not, and moreover it is short by one initial condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic problem  of this formulation is **another differential equation added** instead of **appropriate initial conditions**, namely we shoud have a condition for e.g. `s'[0]` instead of equation for `s'[t]`.  Moreover, it is not quite clear whether we deal with a projectile motion or  with a mathematical pendulum. Next, it appears in the both cases there are wrong signs of the force terms

At this point we should decide what is our  dependent variable `θ` or `s`.  If we prescribe  well posed initial conditions it works well (here `θ` is constant in case of the projectile problem):

```
 s[t] /.  DSolve[{s''[t] == -g Sin[θ], s[0] == 0, 
                          s'[0]^2 == 2 g l Cos[θ]}, s[t], t] // Simplify
```

> ```
> { -Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] t Sqrt[Cos[θ]] +  1/2 g t^2 Sin[θ],
>      Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] t Sqrt[Cos[θ]] +  1/2 g t^2 Sin[θ]}
> ```
>
> also assuming an appropriate initlal condition in case of a pendulum

```
θ[t] /. First @ DSolve[{θ''[t] == - g/l Sin[θ[t]], θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == Sqrt[2 En]}, 
                         θ[t], t]
```

> ```
> 2 JacobiAmplitude[(Sqrt[En] t)/Sqrt[2], ((2 g)/(En l))]
> ```

`En` is an integration constant chosen as an equivalent of the total energy of the pendulum, $E_n=\frac{E}{m\; l^2}$. I should have added this constant in such a form since otherwise `DSolve` refuses to solve this problem.
The result is in terms of a special elliptic function, this can be reformulated in terms of e.g. `JacobiSN` etc:

```
Through @ { Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Csc, Sec} @ JacobiAmplitude[u, m]
```

> ```
> { JacobiSN[u, m], JacobiCN[u, m], JacobiSC[u, m], 
>   JacobiCS[u, m], JacobiNS[u, m], JacobiNC[u, m]}
> ```

This is an exact solution of the pendulum problem, **without assumption of the small amplitude**.  When small amplitudes are considered then trigonometric functions appear to be good approximations of solutions. For comparison we evaluate

```
θ[t] /. DSolve[{ θ''[t] == - g/l θ[t], θ[0] == 0, θ'[0] == Sqrt[2 En]}, 
                 θ[t], t]
```

> ```
>  {(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[En] Sqrt[l] Sin[(Sqrt[g] t)/Sqrt[l]])/Sqrt[g]}
> ```

Taking arbitrary constants of motion we demonstrate the dfifference between exact solution and its approximation by linearizing the differential equation.

```
With[{En = 8, g = 10, l = 1}, 
  Plot[{ Sin[2 JacobiAmplitude[(Sqrt[En] t)/Sqrt[2], (2 g)/(En l)]],
         (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[En] Sqrt[l] Sin[(Sqrt[g] t)/Sqrt[l]])/Sqrt[g]},
    {t, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Thick, WorkingPrecision -> 10, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]

The difference is significant for large amplitudes, while taking e.g. `En = 2` solutions are very close. Finding the amplitudes in the both cases is left for the reader.

Comment: What is `En`? Cause I can find any info in the  Wolfram document.

Comment: I explained this in my answer.  `En == Eng/( m l^2) `, where `Eng` is a total Energy and `m` is the mass of the pendulum.

Comment: Why does `DSolve `  refuse to solve this problem if you don't have added this constant? What's wrong with `DSolve`?

Comment: @kile Not exactly with `DSolve` but with its interaction with elliptic functions. There are various aspects to improve. This is a long story, see e.g. this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63121/integrate-yields-complex-value-while-after-variable-transformation-the-result-i/160055#160055) and references therein. Stictly speaking there are things which should be updated in next versions of the system.

Comment: Why is ```θ'[0] == Sqrt[2 En]```? why not  ```θ'[t] == Sqrt[2 En]```?

Comment: @kile This is an initial condition (one might  choose a different one, however `θ'[t] == Sqrt[2 En]` would be another differential equation not compatible with the equation of motion) namely it is equivalent to expressing velocity (or angular velocity) in terms of the total Energy `Eng`, its true at the time `t=0` and at times which are multiples of the pendulum period, not for every `t`.

Comment: So the initial condition of yours is where the pendulum at its lowest point ?  
Here is a pic for my illustration                                                                                        
                https://i.imgur.com/aF6F8hs.jpg

Comment: @kile Yes, exactly. This graphics might be a good illustration of your question, and so I recommend to include it in your post.

Comment: `En=E/(m l)`, not `En=E/(m l^2)`

Answer (score 3):

Your concept is evidently not adequate. Mathematica contains curated data. That includes knowledge about the physical pendulum. You need to enter

control + = to enter an entity. Then type pendulum. It is the property equations of motion You are looking for. The complete solution is available to, just enter pendulum into Wolfram Alpa built-in or on the web.[image: Curated data physical systems]

```
DSolve[{g Sin[s[t]]/l + s''[t] == 0, s[0] == 0, s'[0] == vmax}, s, t]
```

Output is

```
{{s -> Function[{t}, 
    2 JacobiAmplitude[(t vmax)/2, (4 g)/(l vmax^2)]]}}
```

`vmax = 2 g l Cos[\[Theta]]}`.

Your additional condition is fulfilled too:

```
s'[t]=D[2 JacobiAmplitude[(t vmax)/2, (4 g)/(l vmax^2)],x]=vmax JacobiDN[(t vmax)/2, (4 g)/(l vmax^2)]
```

Corresponding the Mathematica definition of [`JacobiDN`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiDN.html):

```
JacobiDN(u,m)=Sqrt[1-m sin^2(\[Phi])]
```

`m=(4 g)/(l vmax^2)` in this case. `\[Phi])=JacobiAmplitude[u, m]`.

More details for the pendulum is given in the documentation of [`JacobiAmplitude`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiAmplitude.html) in the section for Applications. There are more properties of the solution of the pendulum in the curated data for physical systems [pendulum](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/entity/PhysicalSystem.html). This curated data is new in 12.

```
1/2 (g t^2 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
   2 t (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]] - 
      g t Sin[\[Theta]]))
```

is a solution to the harmonic oscillator in form of a pendulum. This is the approximation of the full problem for small angles. Then is it the angle the approximation of the `Sin` sine.

```
DSolve[{s''[t] == -g/l s[t], s[0] == 0, s'[0] == Sqrt[2 En]}, s[t], t]
```

keep in mind that `m=1` in this case especially in the equation for s'. The solution in general is

```
{{s[t] -> (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[En] Sqrt[l] Sin[(Sqrt[g] t)/Sqrt[l]])/Sqrt[
   g]}}

En = s'[t]^2/2 ==  g l Cos[\[Theta]]
```

for convinience.

Control:

```
s[t] -> 1/
  2 (g t^2 Sin[\[Theta]] + 
    2 t (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]] - 
       g t Sin[\[Theta]]))

s[0]=0
s'[0]=Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]]
s''[t]=-g Sin[\[Theta]]
```

in your solution.

In the free oscillation or small angle solution of mine:

```
s[0]=0
s'[0]=Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]]
s'[t]=Sqrt[2] Sqrt[En] Cos[(Sqrt[g] t)/Sqrt[l]]
s''[t]=-((Sqrt[2] Sqrt[En] Sqrt[g] Sin[(Sqrt[g] t)/Sqrt[l]])/Sqrt[l]
```

)

as required.

Comment: What does `vmax` mean? the maximum velocity?

Answer (score 2):

The initial condition for s' does not depend on t. Write s'[0]^2 ==... You get two solutions you expected..

```
{s1[g_, l_, \[Theta]_], s2[g_, l_, \[Theta]_]} = 
   s /. DSolve[{s''[t] == g Sin[\[Theta]], s[0] == 0, 
s'[0]^2 == 2 g l Cos[\[Theta]]}, s, t]

(*   {Function[{t}, 
        1/2 (-2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] t Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]] + 
 g t^2 Sin[\[Theta]])], 
      Function[{t}, 
       1/2 (2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[g] Sqrt[l] t Sqrt[Cos[\[Theta]]] + 
 g t^2 Sin[\[Theta]])]}   *)

Plot[{s1[1, 1, 1][t], s2[1, 1, 1][t]}, {t, 0, 7}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}]
```