# A hint for an exact solution of a system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I am looking for a curve in two-dimensional space, so $c(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, that satisfies a system of differential equations which could not be solved with *Mathematica*
$$
    x''(t) =  (k - c \;  y(t))\;  y'(t) \\
    y''(t) = -(k - c \; y(t))\;  x'(t)
$$
The differential equations enforce that $c''(t)$ is perpendicular to $c'(t)$, so it is clear that $c'(t)$ always has constant length and it may be assumed this length is $1$.

The constants $k$ and $c$ are both positive. I am interested especially in the case where $k$ is about $1/4$ and $c$ is about $4/1000$, but I think it can be solved with arbitrary positive $k$ and $c$.

The differential equations can be solved quite good numerically.
And I know from numerical computations that a prolate cycloid has nearly the same orbit (path) as the seeked curve. Unfortunately the solution is only nearly a prolate cycloid. One deficiency of a prolate cycloid is that it doesn't have constant velocity $|c'(t)|$.

I would be very glad, if someone could give me a hint to solve these equations.

Comment: Can you please post your code?  That would provide folks more info on what may have gone wrong.

Comment: Also, do not use uppercase names for your variables, especially for single letter ones, as they may conflict with built in symbols. In your case, both `K` and `C` do in fact have built in meaning; it is safer if you replace them with lowercase.

Comment: What are the four conditions? You mean `c(t)` is a phase-space trajectory?

Answer (score 9):

**Symbolic solution**

Even though *Mathematica* cannot solve straightforwardly the original system we can get the symbolic solutions with **a little bit** smarter approach.  Let's observe that we can get rid of `x'[t]` and `x''[t]` from the system by changing variables `y -> z[t] == k - c y[t]`, thus  `z'[t] == -c y'[t]` and `z''[t] == -c y''[t]` therefore `x''[t] == (k - c y[t]) y'[t]` implies that `x''[t] == -1/c z[t] z'[t]`, integrating it we get `c x'[t] + 1/2 z[t]^2 + d == 0`, where `d` is a constant of integration. Inserting this into the second equation yields

```
    z''[t] + 1/2 z[t]^3 + d z[t] == 0
```

This equation **can be solved** in terms of Jacobi elliptic functions:

```
sols = z[t] /. DSolve[{z''[t] + 1/2 z[t]^3 + d z[t] == 0}, {z[t]}, {t}]
```

[image]

Recalling that `z[t] == k - c y[t]` we can easily figure out periodic-like behaviour of `y[t]` found in numerical calculations. In order to get `x[t]` we need inserting `y[t]` into the original system, then integrating with respect to `t`. It seems that we should work with appropriate initial conditions  `y[0]` and `y'[0]` and choose adequate branches of solutions. Then various special cases could clarify the overall behaviour of the system, let's consider a special case.

```
 sd041 = FullSimplify[sols /. {d -> 0, C[1] -> 4, C[2] -> 1}, t > 0]
```

> ```
> {-2 JacobiSN[1 + t, -1], 2 JacobiSN[1 + t, -1]}
> ```

Taking the second equation of the original system we can get `x'[t]` (assuming `c == 1` and `k == 1`):

```
FullSimplify[ D[ sd041[[1]], {t, 2}]/(1 - sd041[[1]]), t > 0]
```

> ```
> (4 JacobiSN[1 + t, -1]^3)/(1 + 2 JacobiSN[1 + t, -1])
> ```

and `x[t]` is (putting the constant of integration equal to zero):

```
xx = Integrate[(4 JacobiSN[1 + t, -1]^3)/(1 + 2 JacobiSN[1 + t, -1]), t]
```

We plot only the real part of `xx` as `x[t]`, (this is because of another issue, see e.g. [Why does Integrate declare a convergent integral divergent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/why-does-integrate-declare-a-convergent-integral-divergent/23082#23082) )

```
Plot[{ Re @ xx, 1 - sd041[[1]]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

and the solution in the phase space is

```
ParametricPlot[{ Re @ xx, 1 - sd041[[1]]}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

At this point it is plausible to exploit numerical capabilities of the system

**Numerical solution**

We can exploit `NDSolve` and including arbitrary initial conditions, we can compare various cases:

```
With[{c = 1/4, k = 4/1000}, 
     ds = NDSolve[{x''[t] == (k - c y[t]) y'[t], 
                   y''[t] == -(k - c y[t]) x'[t], 
                   x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 2, y'[0] == -1},
                   {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 150}]];
{X[t_], Y[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. First @ ds;
```

Now we plot the solution in the range `0 < t < 50`:

```
Plot[{X[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

as well as its derivative

```
Plot[{X'[t], Y'[t]}, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Another interesting feature can be observed with the parametric plot of the solution:

```
ParametricPlot[{X[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 60}]
```

[image]

and it is expected to compare the first and the second derivatives of the solution, we can do it with the animated parametric plot:

```
tab = 
 Table[ ParametricPlot[{{X'[t], Y'[t]}, {X''[t], Y''[t]}}, {t, 0, v}, 
          PlotLegends -> Placed[Style[Row[{"t = ", NumberForm[N@v, {3, 1}]}],
                                        Bold, 20], {Left, Top}], 
          PlotRange -> {{-3.5, 3.5}, {-3.5, 3.5}}], {v, 1, 16, 1/6}];
```

ListAnimate[ tab, Paneled -> False]

[image]

**Edit**

The OP expected solutions with reversed values (`c == 4/1000`, `k == 1/4`)
Then the system behaves in a different way:

```
With[{c = 4/1000, k = 1/4}, 
     ds = NDSolve[{x''[t] == (k - c y[t]) y'[t], 
                   y''[t] == -(k - c y[t]) x'[t], 
                   x[0] == -16, y[0] == 4, 
                   x'[0] == 12, y'[0] == -4}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 130}]];
 {X[t_], Y[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. First@ds;
```

Now the phase space solution is more similar to cycloid-like

```
ParametricPlot[{X[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

```
 ParametricPlot[{{X'[t], Y'[t]}, 
                {X''[t], Y''[t]}}, {t, 0, 100}, 
                PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Playing with different initial conditions we can get various patterns of the behaviour, more or less similar to the previous case with `{c = 1/4, k = 4/1000}`.  Nonetheless from programming point of view the task of examining the system is the same.

Comment: In OP's question `K=1/4` and `C=4/1000`, why you swap it? BTW, thanks for the nice answer.

Comment: @MMM Thanks for pointing out that, indeed now the solution looks a bit different, nevertheless I suppose that imposing  an appropriate initial data, we could get more similar solution. The OP has not mentioned what initial condition are needed.

Comment: Thank you Artes for your nice numerical solutions. The patterns that come out are really beautiful. But I mentioned that I already know how to get a numercal solution. What I am looking for is an analytical solution, that means to have a formula which solves the equation.

Comment: @Miene You are welcome, I'm glad you find this satisfies your expectations, nonetheless you should avoid any ambiguities when asking questions because whoever is trying to answer, finds some confusion. E.g. I see I could set the lenght of $c'(0)=1$ but still there are various ratios $x'(0)/y'(0)$.

Comment: By the way:

Typical initial values for my purpose are

    x(0) = A * cos(phi)
    y(0) = A * sin(phi)
    x'(0) = sin(phi)
    y'(0) = -cos(phi)

with π/2 < phi < π.

But the initial values should not be to crucial.

Comment: Please provide more detail on obtaining `z''[t] + 1/2 z[t]^3 + d z[t] == 0`.  Thanks.

Comment: @Miene There is no claim in the OP that you want to find a symbolic solution. Edit your question, and write unambigously what you've expected.

Answer (score 2):

**Analytical solution with Maple**

Maple is able to produce an analytical solution with out the use of the initial conditions,

```
restart;
Eq1:= diff(x(t),t$2)=(k-c*y(t))*diff(y(t),t$1):
Eq2:= diff(y(t),t$2)=-(k-c*y(t))*diff(x(t),t$1):
dsolve({Eq1,Eq2});
```

[image]

But, if when we specify only two initial conditions ,

```
sol1:=dsolve({Eq1,Eq2,x(0)=a1,y(0)=b1});
```

[image]

```
odetest(sol1,{Eq1,Eq2,x(0)=a1,y(0)=b1})
```

> {0}

If we can take another combination of the conditions,

```
sol2:=dsolve({Eq1,Eq2,x(0)=a1,D(x)(0)=c1});
```

[image]

```
odetest(sol2,{Eq1,Eq2,x(0)=a1,D(x)(0)=c1})
```

> {0}

With these combinations `y(0)=b1,D(y)(0)=d1` and `D(x)(0)=c1,D(y)(0)=d1` maple produces no output.

*Mathematica*'s `DSolve` is unable to solve the system in question analytically.

**Numerical solution with *Mathematica***

```
C1 = 4/1000; K1 = 1/4;

sol1[x0_?NumericQ] := 
  First@NDSolve[{x''[t] == y'[t]*(K1 - C1*y[t]), 
     y''[t] == -x'[t]*(K1 - C1*y[t]), x[0] == x0, x'[0] == x0, 
     y[0] == x0, y'[0] == x0}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 10}];

ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol1[#] & /@ Range[-10, 10, 1]], {t, -10, 
  10}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First I appreciate the revision of my initial question done by Artes. It is much clearer now.
Further I thank all who gave me hints for analytical solutions. In the end I had to accept that there is no really simple solution --- as I posted my question, I had the hope there might be a solution which I just can see even it is not to intricate.

After all I had to go back to a numerical solution and I'll describe my proceeding as it is strait forward and can even be carried out on Excel:

I start with a initial condition c(0) and c'(0) [c'(0) with length 1] and the differential equation gives me c''(0) as

```
x′′(0)=(k−cy(0))y′(0)
y′′(0)=−(k−cy(0))x′(0).
```

Now for a small t I get

```
x'(t)=x'(0)+t*x''(0)
y'(t)=y'(0)+t*y''(0).
```

I normalize c'(t) to length 1 and take the mean value mv(t) = (c'(0)+c'(t))/2, which I normalize likewise. Then I count

```
x(t)=x(0)+t*mvx(t)
y(t)=y(0)+t*mvy(t),
```

where mvx is the x-part of mv an mvy is the y-part of mv. Then I do the same procedure with starting point c(t) and c'(t) to get values for 2*t and so on ...

In this way I get c(n*t) for n=0, 1, 2, 3, ... If t is small enough this will be a fine approximation to the real solution.