# Solve BVP involving user defined function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I have a second order ODE which I would like to solve numerically:

$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+f(y)=0$

BCs: $ y(0) = c$, $y(L)=0$

Where $c$ is a known constant and $f(y)$ is a complicated user defined function, which includes the use of FindRoot.

Naturally, this can be written as a first order system:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\rho$

$\rho\frac{d\rho}{dy} + f(y) = 0$

If $f(y)$ was a nice simple function this could be solved fairly easily since it is separable. However, I'm not sure how to proceed in the case where $f(y)$ is a user defined function which is not known in closed form.

Any suggestions of how to proceed?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163664/use-findroot-inside-ndsolve

Comment: If the answers there do not work in you particular case, a working example for `f[y]` would make it easier for people to try out their ideas.  Also, since it is separable, one can use `NDSolve` to integrate $\int f(y)\; dy$.

Comment: Did you try using `NDSolve`, and if so, what did you do and what went wrong?

Comment: In case of $f(y)=c_1 y$ you have a simple solution in terms of trygonometric functions, for $f(y)= a_3 y^3+a_2 y^2+a_1 y+ a_0$ this can be solved in terms of elliptic functions, for example see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164927/optimization-of-ode-with-respect-to-the-initial-condition/164949#164949) or [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/158654/problem-solving-third-order-non-linear-differential-equation-in-mathematica/158663#158663)

Comment: Moreover take a look at this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138460/a-hint-for-an-exact-solution-of-a-system-of-differential-equations/138464#138464).

Answer (score 2):

As an example suppose `f[y]` is the root of `z^3 + 20 Cos[y] - 1/2`

```
f[y_?NumericQ] := 
        z /. First@FindRoot[z^3 + 20 Cos[y] - 1/2 == 0, {z, 1}]

L = 10; ndsol[c_] := 
          NDSolve[{y''[x] + f[y[x]] == 0, y[0] == c, y[L] == 0}, y, {x, 0, L}]

Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. ndsol[1]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Show the error of the solution

```
Plot[Evaluate[y''[x] + f[y[x]] /. ndsol[1]], {x, 0, 10}, 
    PlotRange -> 10^-4]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already defined the function as `f[y]`, this implies that it **can** be expressed in terms of `y[x]`. So, here is what I suggest:

1. After defining your reference coordinate system, and your domain
   x-y, tabulate (and plot) `f[y]` as a function of `y[x]`.
2. Assuming the function is single-valued, do a curve fit of `f[y]` versus `y[x]` to obtain the closed form expression for `f[y]`. If `f[y]`
   is multivalued, you may need to parametrize f[y] in terms of a new
   parameter `s[x]` or `t[y]`, before you proceed. If you are unable to
   parametrize the multivalued function `f[y]`, you can divide the domain
   into sub-domains where the function is single-valued before you
   proceed to solve the ODE separately for each sub-domain.
3. Assuming that `f[y]` is single-valued along the path `y[x]` in the domain x-y, you can obtain the best fit expression for example, 
   `f[y] = a1 y[x] + a2 y[x]^2 + a3 y[x]^3 + ...` Please note that a polynomial equation may not be the optimal expression for your fit. You need to use some judgement here, using the plot as a guide.
4. Now you are ready to solve the original second order ODE directly, using DSolve, DSolveValue or NDSolve, and the two given boundary conditions.

Example: For the simple case where `f[y]` is a linear function of `y[x]`, the best curve fit yields `f[y]=a1*y[x]`, and given the two boundary conditions, the solution becomes:

```
y[x] = c*Csc[L]*Sin[(L-x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can at least partially solve this if f[y] is integrable.

```
ode = y''[x] + f[y[x]] ==0

DSolve[ode, y[x], x]

(* Solve[Integrate[1/Sqrt[2*Integrate[-f[K[1]], {K[1], 1, K[2]}] + C[1]], 
     {K[2], 1, y[x]}]^2 == (C[2] + x)^2, y[x]] *)
```

Look at the equation to solve and simplify a few things.  Take the positive Sqrt of each side as a starting point.

```
eq = Integrate[1/Sqrt[2*Integrate[-f[K[1]], {K[1], 1, K[2]}] + C[1]], 
     {K[2], 1, y[x]}] == C[2] + x /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2, K[1] -> k1, 
    K[2] -> k2}
(* Integrate[1/Sqrt[c1 + 2*Integrate[-f[k1], {k1, 1, k2}]], 
   {k2, 1, y[x]}] == c2 + x *)
```

Apply the bc's

```
eq /. x -> 0 /. y[0] -> c
(* Integrate[1/Sqrt[c1 + 2*Integrate[-f[k1], {k1, 1, k2}]], 
   {k2, 1, c}] == c2 *)

eq /. x -> L /. y[L] -> 0
(* Integrate[1/Sqrt[c1 + 2*Integrate[-f[k1], {k1, 1, k2}]], 
   {k2, 1, 0}] == c2 + L *)
```

We could possibly solve these equations for `c1` and `c2` if we can integrate `f[y]` either algebraically or numerically, but it is hard to go any further without knowing `f[y]`.